# Descricao grafico em pizza sobreposicao

Tags: pandas, formatação, gráfico

Como resolver isso? Legendas do grafico em pizza se sobrepondo a outras.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi isso com:

```
counts.plot(kind='pie', labels = None, figsize=(11,8), legend=True)
```